# Do I need iptables if only two ports are open to the public?

Tags: server, iptables, firewall

For a special task I have a root server running Linux Ubuntu 14.04. The server has a very minimalistic installation with ssh on a non-standard port and no root access.

Basically the servers primary purpose is to collect and process large amounts of data coming from a number of clients. There is only one single application with a TCP listener handling the client requests.

Last year I've been using iptables and I noticed in my logs many ICMP, DoS and DDoS attacks to my servers ip address. Some of these attacks caused a lot of unwanted traffic. I can see this in the traffic reports I get from my hosting provider. In one case, due to the unusual traffic, my ISP even blocked the access to my server.

As I didn't know how to resolve the issue I temporarilly deactivated iptables and to my big surprise, my traffic statistics went back to normal! Now I'm asking myself what was wrong? Is it even better to have no iptables installed, because I have only 2 ports open to the Internet at all? How can iptables contribute to the protection of my server in this case?

Comment: Please add your `iptables` rules to the question.

Comment: ICMP protocol is mostly used by `ping` command and I'm not sure what exactly the cause was. However, `iptables` are there for a reason and that is to do security implementations.. I'm running many servers with `iptables` and have not come across such issues. However, this is pretty much opinion base as I would say.

Answer (score 2):

Iptables is a firewall which allows you to keep open the nonstandard port *n* for SSH access and block any connection attempt on any other port.  If you disable iptables, you make possible for attackers to try an exploit to any other port and possibly do something malicious to your server (due to a service that you forgot stopping, a bug, or similar).  So yes, you **must** keep it on and configured to open **only** the ports you need.

There is no correlation between the attacks stopping and you disabling iptables -- it was purely by chance.  Either that, or perhaps iptables was misconfigured.

Comment: If I'm not completely wrong there is a difference between having iptables activated or not: if they are activated, the ports are not totally dead, the traffic is handled by iptables and in some cases even producing small amounts of outgoing traffic. If iptables are inactive, the unused ports don't exist at all. I don't expect having any ports open by accident, why should I?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the iptables were configured incorrectly.

Many sites on the internet show iptables rules which restrict the ICMP very strongly or totally block it. Only on the example of ICMP, which has a seemingly very bad reputation. Try to adapt your rules to network requirements, even if it takes some time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question really.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at one of your comments:

> Last year I've been using iptables and I noticed in my logs many ICMP, DoS and DDoS attacks to my servers ip address. Some of these attacks caused a lot of unwanted traffic.

First one to tackle: DDoS.  There's nothing you can do at the server/firewall level to protect against a DDoS.  These're designed to target and overload your entire network pipe, and only the ISPs, really, have any methods to 'filter' out DDoSes.  Most times you have to pay for it (and 99% of residential class connections don't have the option).

Secondly, ICMP and DoS.  ICMP is a very common packet type; it's not necessarily an attack as most of your standard traffic interprets ICMP packets too.  You are likely looking to ratelimit these, rather than outright block them.  DoS is similar, but are going to be attacking your specific software on your system/server to exploit and crash it.

---

Now onto whether `iptables` is at fault.  **It most certainly is not.**  It doesn't generate any of the traffic you've indicated; when configured it will *tell* you about that traffic via log and then drop rules, but it will ultimately *not* be generating that traffic.

---

`iptables` is a firewall - not a comprehensive solution for protecting your server or network from attacks.  It's designed to allow you to have some level of control over what can or cannot connect to your server, what you wish to block automatically given certain criterion, what you wish to block, etc.  It's not going to protect against DoS, and certainly not DDoS.

`iptables` being on or off won't change traffic coming towards your network - what you're seeing is more or less a coincidence, because someone's trying to *access* your server and is just trying again anyways when they fail.  Your ISP is likely *not* blocking the connections based on your `iptables` rules, and are likely instead dropping based on the incoming traffic to your system; this is something you would have to talk to the ISP about.